# Set up Travis CI with Salesforce.com

Tags: deployment, github, ci

I hope someone out there can help setting up Travis CI with Salesforce.com. I started by looking into this guide: http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2015/04/22/travis-ci-salesforce/, So far without luck.

The setup is rather complicated. I have connected Travis CI to github and made the deployment trigger on pull requests. Currently with the following error:

> $ ./build/scripts/setup_credentials.sh /home/travis/build.sh: line 45:
>   ./build/scripts/setup_credentials.sh: Permission denied The command
>   "./build/scripts/setup_credentials.sh" failed and exited with 126
>   during . Your build has been stopped.

So this is my current problem, any suggestions?

If someone can give an example on how to set it up without using solenopsis - that would be even better.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using ant.  The directory structure:

```
├── build.xml
├── lib
│   └── ant-salesforce.jar
├── src
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── HelloWorld.cls
│   │   └── HelloWorld.cls-meta.xml
│   ├── destructiveChangesPost.xml
│   ├── objects
│   │   └── Hello__c.object
│   └── package.xml
└── .travis.yml
```

Create a `build.xml` for the Force.com Migration Tool (the Salesforce Ant library).

```
<project name="Salesforce CRM" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.salesforce" resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" classpath="lib/ant-salesforce.jar"/>

    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="sf.username"      value="${env.SFUSER}"/>
    <property name="sf.password"      value="${env.SFPASS}"/>
    <property name="sf.serverurl"     value="${env.SFURL}"/>
    <property name="sf.maxPoll"       value="500"/>
    <property name="sf.maxWaitMillis" value="3000"/>
    <property name="test.level"       value="NoTestRun"/>
    <property name="check.only"       value="true"/>
    <property name="log.type"         value="None"/>

    <target name="test">
      <sf:deploy
          username       = "${sf.username}"
          password       = "${sf.password}"
          serverurl      = "${sf.serverurl}"
          deployRoot     = "src"
          singlePackage  = "true"
          maxPoll        = "${sf.maxPoll}"
          pollWaitMillis = "${sf.maxWaitMillis}"
          testLevel      = "${test.level}"
          checkOnly      = "${check.only}"
          logType        = "${log.type}"
          ignoreWarnings = "true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Here's a simple `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
script: ant -Dtest.level=RunLocalTests test
env:
   global:
      - SFURL=https://test.salesforce.com
```

Set the `SFUSER`, `SFPASS`, and `SFURL` environment variables either in your `.travis.yml` (like I did with `SFURL`) or in Travis.